# Angular Routing param in the middle

Tags: angular, angular-routing

On my routing module I've a path with some id in the middle. Something like

```
 {
    path: 'detail/:id/new',
    component: SomeComponent
 }
```

In order to have a link to it, I manage two solutions to call it.

**Solution 1:**

```
this.router.navigate(['detail/:id/new', { id: this.myId }]);

Generated URL: http://localhost:4200/myApp/detail/:id/new;id=10
```

**Solution 2:**

```
this.router.navigate(['detail/' + this.myId +'/new']);

Generated URL: http://localhost:4200/myApp/detail/10/new
```

For me, the second solution/URL is more standard and cleaner, but the way to accomplish it seems kind of "hard-coded".

There are some other way to accomplish the solution 2? There are any angular standard?

Comment: this.router.navigate(['detail' , this.myId, 'new']); would also work

Comment: Perfect =) Thanks Can you answer that to mark this question as replied?

Comment: sure, done. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the option that would be least "hard-coded" will look like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['detail' , this.myId, 'new']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try javascript template strings (use ` instead of ')

```
this.router.navigate([`detail/${this.myId}/new`]);
```